# Name for Literary Device

Tags: literary-device

Are the word groups below all fall in the same group, and if so, is there a name for this device?
Examples:
- Jibber jabber
- Flip flam
- Hodge podge
- Trials & tribulations

I thought of alliteration, but the 3rd example doesn't fit.

Comment: Please describe the common theme you're trying to name.

Comment: 1, 2, and 4 are alliteration, 3 is rhyming. Other than the very general term "wordplay", there's no common device that covers them all.

Comment: Jibber jabber and flim flam (note it is not flip) are phrases for gibberish, hodgepodge is a derivative of hotchpotch which is a stew (used to mean nonsense, similar to the first two), and trials + tribulations is exactly what it says. I fail to see a common theme, except that the first three are loosely synonymous

Comment: @AdamMartin The question is about a common literary device, not related meanings.

Comment: My implied point was the only link I saw was in their meanings, as they are by no means all 4 similar devices.